# Font formatting performance in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, performance, vba

I have macro which sets font for whole range to size 9:

```
Range("A1:Z20000").Font.Size = 9
```

When I run it on Excel 2010 or 2013 it takes approximately 1 second to process (there's almost no formatting on range). But when I run it on Excel 2007 it takes 15+ seconds to process this single line of code. I couldn't find any article regarding this, but obviously MS fixed it in newer versions of Office (Excel).

Is there a way to set font size for a big range (500,000+ cells) in Office 2007 without killing performance?

Comment: Can you live with formatting the entire columns to the same font size? I've found that this is often faster... even in Excel 2007

Comment: In Office 2007, if you select that range and change the font via the Menu (or Font preferences), does it also take that long? Or just when you try it with VBA?

Comment: @Excel Hero - it takes about same time (20,437s / 21s)

Comment: @BruceWayne - it takes even more time when changing font size via Excel menu, because in macro I disable screenupdating, etc ...

Comment: do you really need to set the size for all 20,000 rows or is it "a range so large I don't have to worry about it"?  If it's the latter, you may be better off   just formatting the rows you have data rather than n number of rows w/ no data.

Comment: Also, try formatting the entire worksheet and see how long that takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method for your requirement

```
Sub testformat()

Range("A1").Font.Size = 9

Range("A1").Copy

Range("A1:Z20000").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.CutCopyMode = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why turn `CutCopyMode` back on after turning it to false?  If you left it `False`, would it cause issues with using copy later on?

Comment: @BruceWayne  correct., Application.CutCopyMode = True is not required for this program.

Comment: Well, your solutions is quickiest.
`Range("A1:Z20000").Font.Size = 9` takes 20,437 seconds,
`For i = 1 To 26: Columns(i).Font.Size = 10: Next i` takes 21 seconds,
your approach takes 0,359 seconds, I don't really understand why (as it is working with formatting in general, not just font size), but it works the best :) at least for Office 2007

Comment: @user2250595 Welcome. The approach is similar to format painter button.